# How to attach a ForeignKey value in an APIView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Im using Django 1.10 and Django Rest Framework to build an app.

I want to know the "right" way to create a data object and, in the creation process, attach another object as a foreign key.

Consider the following code:

```
#MODEL
class MyModel(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
  # other vars

#VIEW
class CreateModel(generics.CreateAPIView):
  queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

  def create(self, request, *args, **args):
    user = request.user # This User instance needs to be the ForeignKey to MyModel
```

**Question:** Whats the correct way to populate a models ForeignKey field with data from the `request` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion most suitable approach for you is override `perform_create` method.

```
class CreateModel(generics.CreateAPIView):

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thats a really smooth solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Vingtoft your wellcome